# How create and show listview in onDraw method?

Tags: android, view, ondraw

I am new in Android, so please help me. 
In onDraw method I draw a lot of things, which I would like to have as a background. And when I click in the corner, I would like to have listview (with SeekBars, buttons, etc) and everything which i drow before as a background. This background doesn't have to scroll when the listview is scrolling. How to create and set such listview?

My .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.project.MyView
    android:id="@+id/main_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your custom view as background of whole screen . You can do this by making the root view as your custom view .Then calculate the touch on corner and make your child view i.e. list view visible .

Comment: I have never done such hierarchy... So now I should set my listview in my.xml as a new LinearLayout inside this LinearLayout?

Comment: Take Relative layout as root view and then first set custom view as alignparenttop to true and then list view also alignparenttop to true .By doing this both of your views will be on top and take its size .So concept is list view will be inflated upon your custom view now .it will look like custom view is background of whole screen .I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, you help me very much! Thx!

Comment: i asked another question a while ago and this is the answer i wish i recieved!!!!1